# Ruby/NodeJS/Yarn Issue

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, npm, sass, yarn-lock.json

Trying to get a project up and running, but the install of node-sass is problematic. Not sure what's causing this error:

The issue starts when I try to rails db:create - after this command I get an error that says to run yarn install --checkfiles. When I run that, the following happens:

```
$ sudo yarn install --check-files
```

```
Password:
yarn install v1.22.19
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > node-gyp > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > node-gyp > tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request > har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
warning @rails/webpacker > postcss-preset-env > postcss-color-hex-alpha > postcss-values-parser > flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > node-libs-browser > url > querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning @rails/webpacker > optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin > cssnano > cssnano-preset-default > postcss-svgo > svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning @rails/webpacker > optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin > cssnano > cssnano-preset-default > postcss-svgo > svgo > stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
warning popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
warning webpack-dev-server > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
warning webpack-dev-server > webpack-log > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[-/4] ⠂ waiting...
[2/4] ⠂ fsevents
[-/4] ⠂ waiting...
error /Users/pjhagerty/projects/call-of-conduct-admin/node_modules/node-sass: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts/build.js
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/pjhagerty/projects/call-of-conduct-admin/node_modules/node-sass
Output:
Building: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/pjhagerty/projects/call-of-conduct-admin/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/Users/pjhagerty/projects/call-of-conduct-admin/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@16.15.0 | darwin | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "/usr/local/bin/python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/local/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:398:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/pjhagerty/projects/call-of-conduct-admin/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/pjhagerty/projects/call-of-conduct-admin/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
```

I've tried some of the other solutions here, but none resolved the issue.

Comment: I see you also had tried `npm install`. could you delete `package-lock.json` and try again? Also, I think you are missing some pythong packages?

Comment: I deleted my `package-lock.json` and re-ran `npm install` again followed by `sudo yarn install --check-files` but got the same result.